# seleccionar un registro de un p:datatable mediante un p:remoteCommand

Tags: primefaces

Tengo una `p:datatable` con n registros, entre estos un campo con un `p:inputText`, al hacer doble clic sobre éste, llama a un `p:remoteCommand` que ejecuta un método de un `managedBean`.

El problema es que en el método extraigo el registro de donde se origino el evento, pero no me trae el registro correcto, siempre me trae el ultimo registro, favor alguien ayúdeme.

Adjunto codigo:

```
        <p:column style="width:40px;padding-left:1px;text-align:center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Id Orden" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:remoteCommand name="commandDobleClicOrdenrepId" action="#{ordenTrabajoController.dobleClicOrdenrepId}" partialSubmit="true" />                       
            <h:inputText value="#{item.pk.ordenrepId}" ondblclick="commandDobleClicOrdenrepId();" readonly="true" style="border:0;background-color: #fff" 
                title="Dar doble clic desea ver la pre-factura actual."/>                                           
        </p:column>
```

> **ManagedBean**

```
public String dobleClicOrdenrepId(){        
        SeOrdenRep seOrdenRep = (SeOrdenRep) getListadoOrdenes().getRowData();//AQUI ME DA SIEMPRE EL ULTIMO REGISTRO       
        return "form.jsf";  

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por partes:

- `p:remoteCommand` lo único que hace es definir una función JavaScript que hace una invocación a un método en el servidor. La información de qué fila está seleccionada, qué botón llama al JS, etc. simplemente no se envía.
- Como `p:remoteCommand` define una función JS, al meterla dentro del `datatable` lo único que haces es que tu código define la misma función una vez para cada fila. No es muy útil. Sácalo fuera del `datatable`
- Para pasar parámetros al `p:remoteCommand`, se hace tal que así:

  ```
  <h:inputText value="#{item.pk.ordenrepId}"
      ondblclick="commandDobleClicOrdenrepId([{name:'idEdit', value:'#{item.pk.ordenrepId}')"
      readonly="true" style="border:0;background-color: #fff" 
      title="Dar doble clic desea ver la pre-factura actual."/>
  ```

  y en el managed bean lo recoges con un `@ManagedProperty`

  ```
  @ManagedProperty("#{param.idEdit}")  
  private String id;
  ```
- `p:remoteCommand` hace una petición **Ajax**. Es decir, te ejecutará el código que le digas pero no te va a redirigir a otra página.
- Usar "doble click en un campo de texto" para enviar a una página distinta es, por decirlo suavemente, muy poco intuitivo. Usa un `commandLink` o `commandButton`, que para eso están y que todos los usuarios serán capaces de identificar a la primera.